# Is there a way to make Angular.js more verbose when things are undefined?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm really just getting started in earnest with Angular.js and one of the first things I noticed is that it doesn't often throw errors if something isn't found.

In a trivial example, if `something_undefined` is undefined:

```
<p>{{something_undefined}}</p>
```

this will fail silently with:

```
<p></p>
```

In an example with a `$resource`, if I made a typo like `{{member.frist_name}}` I'd quite like Angular to tell me that there was no such attribute `frist_name` on `member`.

Comment: are you using the unminifed version for development? It will offer some more verbose output for you, if you are not already using it.

Comment: I just wasted an hour wondering why my view was empty.   It turns out I was using templateURL instead of templateUrl.  I tried the non-minified version of angular scripts but no error message was shown on the console.  Have you found a general solution to having Angular log this sort of error?

Answer (score 2):

Just for testing purposes you can display an error message instead of empty string by

```
<p> {{ something_undefined || 'Not Found !!!' }} </p>
```

Comment: Good idea! I'll use this if I can't figure out a more general way to do it.

Comment: @tristanm I am still interested in a more general solution that could log warnings or errors to the console without having to modify every place you access data.

Answer (score 1):

This does not aim to be an answer but a related suggestion, coming from my experience and referring also to the other answer, which is indeed useful.

When you start having this kind of problems while developing with angular, write down some tests about it! This way you will keep your code free from extra debugging statements, you will understand better the framework, and you will leave some regression tests after the process. A win on all sides.